# Convolution integral of series involving the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, riemann-zeta-function, convolution

Let us consider the convolution $$f\left(x\right):=\int_{2}^{x-2}\sum_{\rho_{1}}\frac{u^{\rho_{1}}}{\rho_{1}}\sum_{\rho_{2}}\frac{\left(x-u\right)^{\rho_{2}}}{\rho_{2}}du,\,x>4$$ where $\rho_{i},\,i=1,2$ runs over the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta\left(s\right)$. It is possible to observe that $f\left(x\right)$ is a continuous and piecewise smooth function. For a work I need to evaluate $$\frac{d}{dx}f\left(x\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{2}^{x-2}\sum_{\rho_{1}}\frac{u^{\rho_{1}}}{\rho_{1}}\sum_{\rho_{2}}\frac{\left(x-u\right)^{\rho_{2}}}{\rho_{2}}du\right)\tag{1}$$ obviously where it makes sense. My question is:

> How can I handle $(1)$?

My idea was to divide the interval $(2,x-2)$ in a partition $(b_{m},\,b_{m+1}),\,m=1,\dots,M$ such that both $\sum_{\rho_{1}}\frac{u^{\rho_{1}}}{\rho_{1}}$ and $\sum_{\rho_{2}}\frac{\left(x-u\right)^{\rho_{2}}}{\rho_{2}}$ are smooth in $(b_{m},b_{m+1})$ and so differentiate under the integral sign using the Leibniz integral rule, i.e. $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{2}^{x-2}\sum_{\rho_{1}}\frac{u^{\rho_{1}}}{\rho_{1}}\sum_{\rho_{2}}\frac{\left(x-u\right)^{\rho_{2}}}{\rho_{2}}du\right)=$$ $$=\sum_{m=1}^{M-1}\int_{b_{m}}^{b_{m+1}}\sum_{\rho_{1}}\frac{u^{\rho_{1}}}{\rho_{1}}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{\rho_{2}}\frac{\left(x-u\right)^{\rho_{2}}}{\rho_{2}}\right)du+\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{b_{M-1}}^{x-2}\sum_{\rho_{1}}\frac{u^{\rho_{1}}}{\rho_{1}}\sum_{\rho_{2}}\frac{\left(x-u\right)^{\rho_{2}}}{\rho_{2}}du\right)$$ $$=\int_{2}^{x-2}\sum_{\rho_{1}}\frac{u^{\rho_{1}}}{\rho_{1}}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{\rho_{2}}\frac{\left(x-u\right)^{\rho_{2}}}{\rho_{2}}\right)du+\sum_{\rho_{1}}\frac{\left(x-2\right)^{\rho_{1}}}{\rho_{1}}\sum_{\rho_{2}}\frac{2^{\rho_{2}}}{\rho_{2}}$$ and then, from the [explicit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_(L-function)) of the Chebyshev psi function $\psi\left(s\right),$ $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{\rho_{2}}\frac{\left(x-u\right)^{\rho_{2}}}{\rho_{2}}\right)=1-\frac{1}{\left(x-u\right)\left(x-u+1\right)\left(x-u-1\right)}.$$ 
Honestly I'm not sure this argument works.

Comment: $\psi(x) = (x - \sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho}{\rho}-\log 2\pi - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{-2k}}{-2k})1_{x>1}$ converges for $x > 1$ and $\sum_\rho x^{\rho-1} = \frac{d}{dx} 1_{x>1}(x-\psi(x)-\frac12 \log(1-x^{-2})) = C \delta(x-1)+1- \sum_{n=1}^\infty\Lambda(n) \delta(x- n)+ \frac{x^{-3}}{1-x^{-2}}$ converges in the sense of distributions (under the RH with $x = e^u$ it is a Fourier transform pair). Thus you are looking at $\int_1^x (1+\frac{(x-y)^{-3}}{1-(x-y)^{-2}})\psi(y)dy-\sum_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)\psi(x-n)$. Also not sure why you are looking at the additive instead of multiplicative convolution.

Comment: @reuns I'm not familiar with the theory of distributions. Do you think my approach is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: The last line is clearly not correct, you missed the main term $\frac{d}{dx} \psi(x) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \Lambda(n) \delta(x-n)$.